# Is there a strategy for searching for idioms by meaning rather than by words?

Tags: idioms

Say I want to find an idiom that means wasting time/effort, now if I were to search Google or a dictionary with the query

> An idiom that means wasting time/effort

I would get idioms that actually contain the words "wasting", "time" or "effort" in them, but may or may not (often not) mean wasting time/effort.

Thesaurus or search engine, they wouldn't return the idiom "flog a dead horse" which could be the correct answer to my query "An idiom that means wasting time/effort".

So, is there a way to search by meaning?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I'm afraid we can't help you with that for two reasons: 1. We don't know which 'search' you are referring to, and 2. this is a support question for the appropriate site. It has little to do with grammar, word usage or similar topic that are discussed here on EL&U.

Comment: @ALambentEye 1. As in google and online dictionary search 2. I thought this would fall under linguistics; I see your point. So do you know the appropriate site for this question?

Comment: I see, so you are looking for a search engine for idioms, is that correct? Please adjust your question to improve it's clarity  for future readers.

Comment: Not just a search engine for idioms. Mind you, there are tons of them if you know exactly which idiom you are searching for. If you know the idiom all you need to do is type in a keyword in any search engine. My problem is that I don't know the idiom, I know the concept(meaning), and I have to search by that. I think I've expressed this in my question, but if any part of it is still unclear, please point out.

Comment: I've voted to move your question to our Meta site, as resource requests are more on-topic there. (I suspect what you actually need is a curated reference work, rather than a search engine search, but either way this question fits better on Meta.)

Comment: @1006a Yeah, moving to an on-topic site would be good. Actually, that'd be the second way of looking at it, i.e. A reference site, book, etc. that has categorised idioms; this way I could look at the category "sleep" or "drinking" and find all the idioms related to these.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a thesaurus and looking at the synonyms.

In particular I would recommend [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/) for their wide range of phrases.

Another one I use would be [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) (select the "Thesaurus" tab under the search field).

Comment: Please refrain from posting should-be comments as answers.  I know it's off topic.... but can you come to the chat room?

Comment: If you mean finding the synonyms of the meaning and searching by them I've already done that, but all it gives is more idioms with the words I've searched in them that are completely unrelated to the meaning from which the synonyms were obtained.

Comment: What I meant is searching for the idiom, then looking at the list of synonyms.

Comment: @ALambentEye Seems to me you haven't understood the question at all, because that's my very problem, I can't find the idiom by just searching in those sites, let alone finding synonyms for the idiom which I wouldn't need if I could find my desired idiom in the first place. I just need to find one idiom for every meaning, e.g. an idiom that means sleeping or an idiom that means drinking/being drunk etc.
If there's still ambiguity feel free to ask for more explanation.

Comment: @Derp Indeed, I am having trouble understanding your question. I understand your goal is to find an idom (for what purpose I'm not sure). The term you would like to use to find it is an idiom. Where using a thesaurus fails you I do not understand. Could you make an example using an online thesaurus so I could replicate it? Perhaps stating what you would like to expect and what you actually receive?

Comment: @ALambentEye Well I've provided an example in my question, but if that's not clear enough I'll do so again.  
Say I want to find an idiom that means wasting time/effort, now if I were to search with the query "An idiom that means wasting time/effort" I would get idioms that actually contain the words "wasting", "time" or "effort" in them, but may or may not (often not) mean wasting time/effort. Thesaurus or search engine, they wouldn't return the idiom "flog a dead horse" which would be the correct answer to my query "An idiom that means wasting time/effort"....

Comment: Oh I see, I would simply type "waste time" and get [the following results](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/waste%20time). Would that result be what you had in mind?

Comment: ... The only time a thesaurus would be useful is when you know a word of the idiom, for example, "flog" or "horse", either one of these would find the idiom, BUT in my case I don't know the idiom at all so I can't search by word, thus I need to search by meaning.  
I hope this clears it up.

Comment: @ALambentEye Not at all, because that wouldn't get me any closer to "flog a dead horse".

Comment: That would be because "flog a dead horse" [means something else](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/flog%20a%20dead%20horse?s=t), no?

Comment: I see, now that _is_ a problem.

Comment: That would be because "flog a dead horse" is "an idiom that means wasting time/effort", **BUT** does not contain the words "wasting", "time" or "effort", and that is exactly why such websites are useless in my case.If you look up the word "idiom" in a dictionary it says something like "A group of words whose meaning is different from the meanings of the individual words" (from OALD), I need to search by the meaning of the group of words and not by the individual ones.
This'll be my last comment here because a warning stating not to have extended discussions in the comment section has appeared